# Why Apache IoTDB cannot synchronize data with conditions when automatically creating template?

Tags: database, time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

For PIPE settings of Apache IoTDB, when synchronizing A>B, how to configure that B automatically create a time series? I wrote one time series in A, and then automatically created the synchronization time series, but this data cannot be synchronized with B, because B does not have this time series. I can only synchronize data from A to B after manually creating time series in B. Does the current version not support automatic creation of time series in B during synchronization? Or what did I understand wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When writing data in A of Apache IoTDB, and then automatically create a time series, when B also enables the automatic creation of metadata, then this data can be synchronized to B, and there is no need to manually create time series in B. If your current sender is in a template time series, the data cannot be synchronized directly, so you need to create a corresponding time series at the receiver before you can synchronize data.